# Security of rails user access/permissions plugins

Tags: appsec, web-application, session-management, rails

I was wondering if anyone knows what the most secure user access plugin for Rails is, and if any of them prevent session fixation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Ruby on Rails security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation) as long as you're using the reset_session command during the authentication process, you should be mitigating against session fixation attacks.  In general with a rails app. if you're only creating the session when the user logs in and you're issuing a new Session ID at that point, you shouldn't have too many problems with session fixation.